# Notice: Undefined index: entity_type_id

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I am using datapatch to update attribute
  my code is

```
 namespace Devall\SpecialPrice\Setup\Patch\Data;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;

class AddLabaCenaAttribute implements DataPatchInterface

protected $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetup $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function apply()
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4, 184, 'is_used_for_promo_rules', 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong ID (not entitytypeid,true ID) so It was thinking entitytypeid was wrong.